# Move from an activity to another one in View Class in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity that has two classes like these:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {
    .
    .
    .
}

public class StartView extends View {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I want to go from this Activity to another one with click on one image.Is there any method (such startActivity method in Activity Class) in View Class that I can use it in the Second Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
public class startView extends View {

    Activity mActivity;
    Context mContext;

    public startView(Activity yourActivity, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub         
        super(context, attrs);
        this.mActivity = yourActivity;
        this.mContext = context;
        init();

    }

    public void init()
    {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IMAGEVIEWID);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, SecondActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes,but startActivity method don't usable in View Class.

Comment: Check my edit: -in your construtor, call the activity and context, and use it to call Intent and startactivity.